# Disable touch input temporarily when digitizer pen within range

Tags: windows-7

I recently bought a Lenovo x220, and I have been having problems with accidental touch clicks and other gestures being registered while I am writing with the digitizer pen. I have tried disabling touch input completely, and this stopped all of the accidental clicks.

Ideally I would like to leave touch input enabled, but have it automatically disabled when the digitizer pen is within range of the screen (which is approximately 1 inch above the screen).

I have tried to do some searching online for potential solutions, but I made little progress.